# Container docker & Kubernetes apache tomcat 8.5.56 http status 404

Tags: docker, tomcat, kubernetes

please I'm running a .war application on apache tomcat 8.5.56 in a docker container and everything work well, but when I create deploy the container on Kubernetes I can access my application welcome page: I have the error message

```sh
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found

Type Status Report

Message The requested resource [/SmartClass] is not available

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
Apache Tomcat/8.5.56
```

Please anyone knows how to solve it?

For the deployment I have just copied the .war file into
`/opt/apache-tomcat/webapps/` and I have copied my server.xml file into `/opt/apache-tomcat/conf/`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is related to the connection to the application.

1. Create a Service object that exposes your Tomcat deployment:

   ```sh
   kubectl expose deployment tomcat-example --type=NodePort --name=example-service
   ```
2. Display information about the Service:

   ```sh
   kubectl describe services example-service
   ```

   The output is similar to this:

   ```sh
   Name:                   example-service
   Namespace:              default
   Labels:                 run=lexample
   Annotations:            <none>
   Selector:               run=example
   Type:                   NodePort
   IP:                     10.32.0.16
   Port:                   <unset> 8080/TCP
   TargetPort:             8080/TCP
   NodePort:               <unset> 30000/TCP
   Endpoints:              10.200.1.4:8080,10.200.2.5:8080
   Session Affinity:       None
   Events:                 <none>
   ```

   Make a note of the NodePort value for the service. For example, in the preceding output, the NodePort value is 30000.
3. List the pods that are running the Tomcat application:

   ```sh
   kubectl get pods --selector="run=example" --output=wide
   ```

   The output is similar to this:

   ```sh
   NAME                           READY   STATUS    ...  IP           NODE
   tomcat-2895499144-bsbk5   1/1     Running   ...  10.200.1.4   worker1
   tomcat-2895499144-m1pwt   1/1     Running   ...  10.200.2.5   worker2
   ```
4. Get the public IP address of one of your nodes that is running a Tomcat pod. How you get this address depends on how you set up your cluster. For example, if you are using Minikube, you can see the node address by running  `kubectl cluster-info`. If you are using Google Compute Engine instances, you can use the  `gcloud compute instances list`  command to see the public addresses of your nodes.
5. On your chosen node, create a firewall rule that allows TCP traffic on your node port. For example, if your Service has a NodePort value of 31568, create a firewall rule that allows TCP traffic on port 30000. Different cloud providers offer different ways of configuring firewall rules.
6. Use the node address and node port to access the Hello World application:

   ```sh
   curl http://<public-node-ip>:<node-port>
   ```

   where  `<public-node-ip>`  is the public IP address of your node, and  `<node-port>`  is the NodePort value for your service.
   Please adjust above command according to proper names and values you have used.

Comment: What is your mountPath of persistent storage in deployment file?